# Get the html of the tag including itself

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to read each child node of a div.

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
<p>First element.</p>
<p>Second element.</p>
<p>Third element.</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Fourth element</td>
        <td>Still the fourth element</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Fifth element.</p>
```

I want an array with:

```
children[0] = '<p>First element.</p>';

children[1] = '<p>Second element.</p>';

children[2] = '<p>Third element.</p>';

children[3] = '<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Fourth element</td>
        <td>Still the fourth element</td>
    </tr>
</table>';
children[4] = '<p>Fifth element.</p>';
```

What I tried with JQuery :

```
$('#page_html_source').children().each(function () {
    var line = $(this).html();
    children.push(line);
});
```

This gives me:

```
children[0] = 'First element.';

children[1] = 'Second element.';

children[2] = 'Third element.';

children[3] = '
    <tr>
        <td>Fourth element</td>
        <td>Still the fourth element</td>
    </tr>';
children[4] = 'Fifth element.';
```

This is without its wrapping tags and that's what I need.

Is there an alternative to *html()* that gets the wrapping tags also?

Comment: You could try to use: `var line = $(this).prop('outerHTML');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the power of javascript:

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

```js
$('#page_html_source').children().each(function () {
    var line = this.outerHTML
    children.push(line);
});
```